# Quick fix to clarify markdown help for comments

Tags: feature-request, markdown, help, editing-help

I'm pretty ashamed to admit how often I mix up the hyperlink markdown when writing a comment, but I see this error often enough throughout the network that I wonder if a small fix could help alleviate it.

Currently, the dropdown help menu for writing comments says `Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com)`. This leads to occasional problems where someone will put the URL itself in between the square brackets and the "clickable" text in parentheses.

I wonder if a small change—writing `[clickable link]` or `[clickable text]` in the dropdown menu, or something similar—would help reduce these errors and the possible confusion and edits they may bring up.

Comment: Or just `text` instead of `link`?

Comment: @rene That would work as well. Really, anything that would prevent a user from thinking "the actual URL."